# Best way to find if two nodes are connected given a set of nodes on a JSON file

Tags: python, json, algorithm, graph

I'm new to programming, so I'm sorry if some things/details seem trivial to you.

So, I have a JSON file on which there a set of points (or nodes) where each node has two coordinates and an ID. I also have a "limit" (i.e if distance between two points is less or equal to this limit, then the two points are said to be connected, giving me a graph). I want to write a program in python that tells me, if I give it two points, if these points are connected (directly or indirectly) or not.

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "limit": 32.0,
  "nodes": [{
      "y": 9.0,
      "x": 65.0,
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "y": 44.6,
      "x": 3.4,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "y": 1.5,
      "x": 98.9,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "y": 2.67,
      "x": 7.0,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "y": 3.0,
      "x": 65.0,
      "id": 4
    }
  }]
}
```

Therefore, I created a class, called Nodes, and from the JSON file I managed to create a set of Nodes and to obtain my "limit".

My problem now, is that I'm stuck. I don't know what to do.

From the internet searches I have conducted, I have found that I had to use the "Depth-First Search" algorithm to solve my problem. But I have some trouble implementing it, since most examples I found used graphs (edges and so on) to implement the algorithm, while I only have the nodes.

So, if you could give me a hint, that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Can you give a small example of the JSON-file? Just 2 or 3 nodes, to have the syntax.

Comment: There you go, sir

Comment: and please fix your JSON by adding `]}`, so other can just copy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `networkx` as graph library.
Then the following code should do the job. In the last line just insert your desired IDs.

```
import networkx as nx
import json

def dist(u,v):
  return (u['x']-v['x'])**2 + (u['y']-v['y'])**2

input_file = open('input.txt','r')
data = json.load(input_file)
input_file.close()
G = nx.Graph()

for v in data['nodes']:
  G.add_node(v['id'])
  G.nodes[v['id']].update(v)
for i in range(len(G.nodes)):
  for j in range(i):
    if dist(G.node[i], G.node[j]) < data['limit']:
      G.add_edge(G.node[i], G.node[j])

print(nx.has_path(G, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Yeah it actually is MUCH simpler with networkx. Thanks a lot.